# WSO2 - Set a property and write it in the Carbon Log

Tags: class, logging, wso2, mediator

I've created a Custom Proxy and added a class mediator and log Mediator in it. I'm trying to set a property's value in the java class and need to write that in the log, as the proxy gets deployed. But, so far, haven't got any success.

I've tried adding a parameter in the Log mediator and used the get-property() method but it still doesn't print it. If I use a 'Property' mediator itself, then I'm able to write the value in the log but that's not our purpose here.

I've also tried using log.debug in the java class, just to write the usual 'entering/exiting a function', but to no respite.

Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How are you setting a property in the java class(ie: in your class mediator)?
It should be like;

```
synapseMesssageContext.setProperty(key,value);
```

Then,In the sequence flow access it as;

```
<property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"   name="testing the property"
                expression="get-property('key')"   scope="default"/>
```

Comment: Here is the portion of the mediate method in which I'm using the property

public boolean mediate(MessageContext mc) {
     mc.setProperty("SomeProp", "SomeValue");

return true;
}
I need to get this SomeProp's value in the log.

Or,

Would it be possible to first set a property using the Property mediator and then access it in the java class? Would it be visible to the class to get/set its value?

Comment: You can do both ways, if you set the property first in the class mediator, you can access as i mentioned in my reply..Or else, if you set that in the sequence, you can get it in the classmediator like, messagecontext.getproperty(key). ..Only thing is the order. If you want to set the property in the class meditor, you have to keep that in the sequence before accessing that in the logmediator. Likewise, if you want to retrive the property in the classmediator, you have to keep taht classmeditor after your property mediator..

Comment: These posts may help you. http://vvratha.blogspot.com/2013/03/accessing-various-information-of.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use log.info to print any log messages. Please reffer [1] which has logged messages using log.info.

[1]http://wso2.org/library/2898